# Axis 2 WS Top to Down Approach from WSDL Issue with Service URL

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

This is my Problem

I have a WSDL from which I am creating web service by top to bottom approach using AXIS 2.
What I cant do is.

Cannot Change the endpoint url for the second service I create using the same WSDL.

I cannot change the service tag in WSDL url. By which we can change the endpoint address.

```
    In short I need to change the service name on the second step in eclipse 
    Wizard.But the WSDL must match the given one.
```

As the specification is such a way that the wsdl must match what they provide to me expect for the endpoint address

Any help on how can this be achieved using AXIS2 ?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

It is a hack or a ugly way to achieve it.

Create the web service using top to bottom approach twice with diff implementation package

Now the renaming part which is the problem with AXIS 2 Wizard.

In the web-inf folder we will have to create a folder with the new Service name And copy the class file for the new implementation package  And edit the services.xml as below

```
    <service name="THE NAME YOU WANT">
```

..
 ..
..

```
    <parameter name="ServiceClass">YOUR IMPL CLASS HERE</parameter>
```